# How to delete a redundant space in responsive website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I make my website responsive with a lot of screen, without bootstrap just with @media + code CSS3

All think is right and correct but in the phone size, that's work but I have a small problem

I have a redundant space I want to delete him

Pictures of site And problem :

- Site :

[http://www.shy22.com/upfilpng/xv854884.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6WJU.jpg)

- problem :

[http://www.shy22.com/upfilpng/nc854884.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Vpz.jpg)

Code CSS :

```css
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

.players {
    margin: -89px 0px 0px -21px;
}

.logo {
 margin: -62px 0px 0px 49px;
}

.publicity {
 display: block;
 width: auto;
 height: 65px;
 background: #FFF url("img/pubb1.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
 margin-top: 320px;
 }

}
```

Comment: That's the horizontal scrollbar from the Mobile Developer Tool of Firefox

Comment: You need to also show the HTML corresponding to this code. Also, try to explain the problem better. Also, try adding `border: 1px solid red` to your elements to have a better idea of the box model.

Comment: @light I make the border, it's take all the page :'( I have the problem in Players because if I delete their all think come on right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is an element that overflow to the right, you have two solution:

- Inspect all the elements and find one that overflow
- Apply an `overflow-x:hidden;` to html and body tags